# How do I represent enum variants in json for serde?

Tags: oop, rust, type-conversion, serde

I'm trying to create objects from text, so I decided to use serde, but I'm struggling to write json for enum variants. This is a simplified version of the OOP I want to convert json to:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Spell {
    kind: Kind
}
```

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Kind {
    Particle(Particle)
}
```

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Particle {
    mass: f64
}
```

I'm using this simple function to turn the json into the a `Spell` object:

```
fn create_spell_from_json(spell_json: &str) -> Result<Spell, serde_json::Error> {
    let spell: Spell = serde_json::from_str(spell_json)?;
    Ok(spell)
}
```

So now how do I represent Particle in json? I'm not sure if it's possible, if not, I'm very open to suggestions as so far all I can write is this: `{"kind": "Particle"}` But this doesn't give any values to Particle and throws a runtime error because of it.

Comment: serde has many options for enum. How would you want it?

Comment: Just as a tip, in a situation where you don't know what exactly you need to write in the serial format, you can often just derive `Serialize`, construct a sample in Rust and [let the `Serializer` of your format spit something apropriate out](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3824a58eb324ff5d0e2ccbfb39b1f371)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default encoding for enums is [externally tagged](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#externally-tagged). An example:

```json
{
    "kind": {
        "Particle": {
            "mass": 0.1
        }
    }
}
```

However you can customize it in many ways, see the page linked above.